# Focus lost notification in NSView (WebView)

Tags: cocoa, webkit

Is there a way to receive a notification when a certain Cocoa WebView loses focus?

Thanks!

Solved

```
- (void)webViewDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
```

does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. One workaround I use effectively (and found somewhere online) is to subclass NSWindow and override -update. Here you can post a notification passing the window's current firstResponder as the notification object. In your app-specific controller(s) you can listen for this notification and compare the current firstResponder with the previous or some other "did we lose focus" check and respond appropriately.